# Similar to vsprintf, implemented to use dynamically created array of strings instead of a va_list

Tags: c, string-interpolation

String interpolation with n-variables commonly involve variadic functions. In C, is there an alternative similar to `vsprintf` that can take a dynamically created array of strings instead of a va_list?

```
int foo (char *s, const char *format, char **strs );
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such function in the C standard library.

Given that your format string will be quite limited (only supporting `%s` and perhaps width modifiers), you might be able to implement this yourself by parsing the format string.

Answer (score 0):

There is not, but you can write your own function, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char *strdup(const char *);

int foo(char *str, const char *fmt, char **arr)
{
    int cnt = 0, len = 0, bit = 0;
    char *buf, *ptr, *tmp;

    /* fmt must be writable */
    buf = ptr = strdup(fmt);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((tmp = ptr)) {
        while ((ptr = strchr(ptr, '%'))) {
            /* Support for %% */
            if (ptr[1] == '%') {
                ptr += 2;
                continue;
            }
            /* Skip first % */
            if (bit ^= 1) {
                ptr += 1;
                continue;
            } else break;
        }
        if (ptr) *ptr = '\0'; /* Tokenize */
        len += sprintf(str + len, tmp, arr[cnt++]);
        if (ptr) *ptr = '%'; /* Untokenize */
    }
    free(buf);
    return len;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *arr[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    char str[100];

    foo(str, "%s, %s, %s", arr);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```